# update $auto_path of tcl script,include a variable in it

Tags: tcl

I'm a newer to tcl script.

lappend can add a path in $auto_path.

but if I want to update the auto_path,or delete an old path,then add a new path to the $auto_path,which command can do it?

and another question, 
I want to include a variable in $auto_path.

like

```
%puts $auto_path
%/usr/local/lib/tcl8.5 /usr/local/lib $(PROJECT_HOME)/tools/lib
```

$(PROJECT_HOME) will be set before project build.

how to set it?

Comment: You seem to be using Tcl 8.5, consider upgrading to Tcl 8.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, treat the value of `auto_path` as a Tcl list using the list commands like lappend. As for your specific questions:

> I want to include a variable in $auto_path.

In the preamble of your Tcl script, you need to access this environment variable (see [`tclvars`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M5)) and append it to the list:

```
if {[info exists ::env(PROJECT_HOME)]} {
   lappend auto_path $::env(PROJECT_HOME)
}
```

> or delete an old path,then add a new path

Consider using [`lset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm):

```
% lappend auto_path /path/to/your/tools/lib
/opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 /opt/local/lib /path/to/your/tools/lib
% lset auto_path end /another/path/to/your/tools/lib
/opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 /opt/local/lib /another/path/to/your/tools/lib
```

Comment: You can `lappend auto_path [file join $env(PROJECT_HOME) tools/lib]` to build a path by pieces from a defined root.